# ftp_put() carga el archivo pero en el trayecto al hosting se corrompe

Tags: php

El programa funciona "correctamente", es decir, toma la imagen de la super global `$_FILES`, valida que sea una extension permitida, comprueba que no exceda los 50MB, genera un id unico para tal imagen, dejo una copia de tal imagen en mi computadora en una carpeta local que tengo del sitio como respaldo, se conecta pasivamente a mi hosting a traves de una conexion pasiva de FTP, sube el archivo con el nombre correcto en el directorio correcto (por eso digo que todo el proceso funciona "correctamente") pero cuando me meto a mi cpanel (al file manager) y entro a la carpata en donde guarde la imagen, veo que si aparece, pero cuando la abro no se mira... Sospecho que en el trayecto la imagen se corrompe porque el tamaño de la imagen no coincide con la imagen original. Aca les dejo el codigo...

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('X','X','X','X');

    $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
    $fecha = date("m/d/Y");
    
    
    $imagen_nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    $imagen_tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];
    $imagen_nombre_temporal = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
    $error =  $_FILES['imagen']['error'];
    
    $nota = $_POST["noticia"];
    $autor = "Gerardo Topete";
        
    if($imagen_tamano > 5000000){
        echo 'La imagen es muy grande. Intenta con una medida mas pequeña';
    }
    else{
        $imagen_extension = pathinfo($imagen_nombre, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);   
        $imagen_extension_minusculas = strtolower($imagen_extension);
        $extensiones_permitidas = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
        
        if(in_array($imagen_extension_minusculas, $extensiones_permitidas)){
            $nuevo_nombre_imagen = uniqid("IMG-", true).'.'.$imagen_extension_minusculas;
            $directorio_imagenes = 'imagenes/'.$nuevo_nombre_imagen;
            
            move_uploaded_file($imagen_nombre_temporal, $directorio_imagenes);
            
            $guardar_nota = "INSERT INTO XXXXXX (titulo, fecha, imagen, noticia, autor) VALUES ('$titulo', '$fecha', '$nuevo_nombre_imagen','$nota','$autor')";
    
            //Si se inserta correctamente cargar el archivo al servidor
        
            if(mysqli_query($conexion, $guardar_nota)){
                $ftp_servidor = "ftp.punkconleche.com";
                $ftp_conexion = ftp_connect($ftp_servidor, 21) or die("No pudimos conectarnos con el servidor");
                $sesion = ftp_login($ftp_conexion, "X","X");
                
                ftp_pasv($ftp_conexion, true);
                
                $imagen = $directorio_imagenes;
        
                if(ftp_put($ftp_conexion, "public_html/imagenes/$nuevo_nombre_imagen", "C:/wamp64/www/punkconleche/imagenes/$nuevo_nombre_imagen", FTP_ASCII)){
                    echo "Archivo cargado correctamente <br/>";
                    echo $nuevo_nombre_imagen;
                }
                else{
                    echo "Hubo un error desconocido al cargar el archivo";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ftp_close($ftp_conexion);
?>
```

Comment: No entendí el problema. ¿Dónde está la imagen originalmente (en el cliente y quieres pasarla al servidor o al revés), por qué usas la base de datos y por qué usas FTP para esto?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que es una pagina a la cual subo ariticulos que contienen imagenes por eso hice un formulario en mi computadora que lo uso para redactar articulos y cargarlos a mi sitio web.